# How to schedule automatic SQL backup via phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, backup

My provider does not allow access to my MySQL database from outside.
Only when you are logged on to their server or control panel and the into phpMyAdmin.
I have set up an automatic backup of files via ftp to my local computer using Iperius Backup.
It works fine.  But I need to do the same to my database and the software has that option but since my provider does not allow access from outside it is not possible.
Is it possible to make a script or something that for example every day export the database to an sql file and store it on the webhotel were all php files are located ??
In that way the database backup will be backed up together with the other files.

Or is there another way to do this ?

Thank you for your help.

Petter

Not much I can try without help.